# Multiple chrome driver instances

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Any idea how to / or if it is even possible to run 2 or more chrome driver sessions and robotframework tests ?
I have a web page and need to test cases for 2-3 different users logged in.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried opening multiple windows with a single driver?

Comment: Hmm interesting idea, how do u mean it ? I have two separated test files. And with each test suite i create chrome driver instance with new profile stored in my own dir not using default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Open Browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}  #for user 1
...
Open Browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}  #for user 2
...
Open Browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}  #for user 3
...
```

try to use "Open Browser" every time when you use this the new browser window will open..below every Open Browser write down your code for log in.

Comment: Thanks, I use my own function and i edited it to create new profile with is parameter when i run robot test.

`Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --user-data-dir\=TESTDATA`
And then i use `python -v chromefolder:name test.robot` to run test. That way I can run two or more tests simultaneously.

Thanks guys for idea

Comment: It worked on windows but on linux it is not working.
I have test running on jenkins.